# R - Remove the Columns from a data-frame if they are Identical

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame which has more than 100 columns and 10000 rows. Manually checking the data in each column if all the rows in that column are same and then removing it is becoming a harder task.

So, I am looking for a function that will take my data-frame as input and output another data-frame that will have columns only which are not identical.

Input data-frame will be something like:

```
data<- read.table(text = "
A B C D
1 1 3 4
1 2 2 4", header = TRUE)
```

and I want the output data-frame to be:

```
B C
1 3
2 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Henrik Actually, I could have applied it. But I am learning along. Sorry, mate. Finding very difficult to understand this sapply, lapply and apply concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through each columns using `sapply`. Then, for each columns check if all elements are equal to the first element.

```
data[!sapply(data, function(x) all(x == x[1]))]
#  B C
#1 1 3
#2 2 2
```

---

Results of `microbenchmark` is shown below. Note that `db()` in this case was

```
db = function(){
    df[!sapply(df, function(x) all(x == x[1]))]
}
```

All the other functions and data are from [coffeinjunky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987110/7128934).

```
with(microbenchmark(db(), ak(), ak2(), ak3(), cj(), cj2()),
     boxplot(x = split(time/1e6, expr), outline = FALSE, ylab = "milliseconds"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One option would be `Filter` to keep only the columns that have `length` of its `unique` elements greater than 1

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))>1, data)
#  B C
#1 1 3
#2 2 2
```

---

Or another option is `sapply`

```
data[sapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x)))>1]
```

Or with `anyDuplicated`

```
data[!sapply(data, anyDuplicated)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a few options here:

If all elements are identical, this means the minimum and the maximum will be the same. Note that these are highly optimized built-in functions. Similarly, if all elements are identical, the variance is 0. In code:

```
df[, !sapply(df, function(x) min(x) == max(x))]
df[, !sapply(df, function(x) var(x) == 0)] # if all numeric
```

If it is a performance issue, let's compare:

```
# 100 columns and 10000 rows with duplicates:
df <- data.frame(
  matrix(rnorm(10000*50),ncol=50),     # 50 columns, non-repeating
  matrix(1:50, ncol=50)[rep(1,10000),] # 50 columns, identical elements
  )

ak <- function(){
  Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))>1, df)
}
ak2 <- function(){
  df[sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))>1]
}
ak3 <- function(){
  df[!sapply(df, anyDuplicated)]
}
cj <- function(){
  df[, !sapply(df, function(x) var(x) == 0)]
}
cj2 <- function(){
  df[, !sapply(df, function(x) min(x) == max(x))]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ak(), ak2(), ak3(), cj(), cj2())    

Unit: milliseconds
  expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  ak()   17.472319   17.870399   19.586547   19.040228   19.762838   66.545086   100
 ak2()   17.412296   18.152165   19.830981   19.127153   19.908074   65.856221   100
 ak3()   11.359604   11.608405   12.475312   11.939775   12.966077   18.132573   100
  cj()    6.799404    7.043694    7.466027    7.175871    7.472253   10.451793   100
 cj2()    4.068508    4.237848    4.306551    4.279522    4.373600    4.901368   100
```

The built in `min` and `max` functions are supposedly highly optimized, which   explains the good performance. I am almost surprised that `var == 0` did so well, given the many computations that are involved (computing the mean, subtracting the mean from all elements, squaring the result, sum).